# How to sort defaultdict(list) such that all lists are sorted based on one key?

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting, csv

To all amazing programmers,

I would like to know how I can sort a defaultdict(list) collection such that the sort order of one list (e.g. defaultdict(list)[list1]) is applied to the remaining lists as well. Perhaps a short description/example is more useful. If there is a better way of doing this I am also all ears.

Example Problem:
I had a .csv file consisting of many columns (different data types) and a headerline. Using defaultdict(list) I import the .csv file using:

```
data = defaultdict(list)
Reader = csv.DictReader(open(FilePath, 'r'))
for (k,v) in row.items():
    data[k].append(v)
```

Now I am left with a *defaultdict(list)* named 'data' of structure:

```
data = [('varA', <list of n time.struct_time items>),
        ('varB', <list of n other data type items>)',
        ('varC', <list of n other data type items>)']
```

Each list (varA, varB, varC) has the exact same number of items. Assuming varA is not ordered, how would I order all data entries based on varA.

I know that

```
sortOrder = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(data['varA']), key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

Returns a list with the correct order of the indexes. Is there a way to apply this order to the other lists.

*NOTE:* I read somewhere that

```
data[varB] = data[varB][sortOrder] 
data[varC] = data[varC][sortOrder]
```

would give me the correct answer, given that sortOrder is an array (its not, the above yields a list). Problem is how can I, without using numpy, convert the sortOrder list to an array.

Comment: Your example code is missing something; where does `row.items()` come from? Is it `for row in csv:` ?

Comment: Hey buddy, row.items() comes from the csv module, as do the key and value pair associated with each row item.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would:

- Pair up list VarA with numbers 1 to n, so:

  - `[ b, a, c ]` becomes `[ (1,b), (2,a), (3,c) ]`
- Sort the new list by value, so:

  - `[ (2,a), (1,b), (3,c) ]`
- Unpair them and the way the numbers end up, is the ordering for the other lists:

  - `[2,1,3]`  How to make the list into order: take the second item, the first item, the third item.
- For each row, take the items in that order into a new list

Untested example code:

```
sort_holder = [(index, item) for (index, item) in enumerate(data['VarA'])]
sort_holder = sorted(sort_holder, key = lambda pair: pair[1])
new_order = [pair[0] for pair in sort_holder]

for var, row in data.items():
    new_list = []
    for index in new_order:
        new_list.append(row[index])
    data[var] = new_list
```

Comment: This is sufficient to answer my problem. Thank you for your quick response!